# Running the same sed transformation on a large number of files

Tags: linux, shell, sed

A bug in some code I wrote resulted in some files being formatted incorrectly. If it were only one file, I could write

```
cat filename | sed 's/bad/good/g' >filename2
mv filename2 filename
```

and fix it. I have several hundred files, however, and I would like to make the same transformation on all of them.

**Is there some way to apply the same transformation to a large number of files with sed, keeping the filenames the same?**

**Is sed even the right tool for this job? If not, what should I use?**

Comment: Actually, `cat filename | ... >filename` can leave you with an empty file: The shell sets up the pipeline, including truncating the output file, _before_ exec'ing the tools (such as cat) being run.

Comment: @Charles Duffy: I fixed the bug in my example code; I don't want anyone stumbling across this question to lose an important file.

Comment: It can leave you with an empty file, and one angry `cat` that has been uselessly used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `-i` (in-place) option on modern versions of sed.

```
sed -i 's/bad/good/g' file*pattern
```

or, with find

```
find . -type f -name 'file*pattern' -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's/bad/good/g'
```

If you're concerned about something going awry, you can supply a suffix as an argument to `-i`, and a backup copy of each file will be saved with that suffix before the transformation is applied:

```
sed -i.bak 's/bad/good/g' filename
diff filename.bak filename
```

If your version of sed doesn't support the `-i` option, you can always use perl, which is where sed got the idea (only fair, since much of perl's command-line syntax comes from sed):

```
perl -pi.bak -e 's/bad/good/g' filenames
```

Comment: How modern are we talking? Is RHEL 5 new enough?

Comment: No need for xargs with modern find: `find ... -exec sed -i 's/bad/good/g' '{}' +` (as opposed to the older `-exec ... {} ... ';'` variant) will transform multiple files per sed invocation just as xargs does.

Comment: @Dan yes, RHEL 5 is fine for `sed -i`... as with pretty much any GNU sed you'll find in circulation.

Comment: Thanks, @CharlesDuffy.  Good to know.  I'm a creature of ancient habit ; I still tend to use `find | xargs grep` instead of `grep -r`, too.

Comment: I would not back up the individual files, but the entire tree with `cp -a tree tree-NEW` (or `cp -dpr` or whatever the non-GNU equivalent is for `cp -a`). Do the work in `tree-NEW`. Then if something goes wrong you can just blow that off and try again. Use `diff -urN tree tree-NEW` to see the differences that have been made to verify all is okay.